# Correlation: how much skew is too much?

Tags: correlation, skewness

Most data for which Pearson correlations are calculated are not truly normal. I've seen textbooks cite +/- skewness of 2.0 as "too much skew" to rely on correlations as measures of association strength, yet I do not know of any real analysis of how robust correlations are to the influence of skewness. At what point would you consider using either a transformation or some kind of alternative model? The simplicity of a correlation is desired in my case, unless it's not "valid" to do so.

Comment: Are both of your variables skewed or just one? That can make a difference. See, for example, this article: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b6cf/001cbab0375a96c370585462dd3c163669af.pdf. Other potentially useful link: http://www.pbarrett.net/techpapers/skewness.pdf.

Comment: @Tom are you primarily concerned about *estimating* a linear correlation, or *testing* one?

Comment: It's not skewness you need to worry about, it's nonlinearity. You can always get a P-value without worrying overmuch about failure of marginal normality.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in both estimating the strength of association and providing an inference (e.g., using a p-value or CI)

Comment: @Nick Skewness translates to unexpectedly large variance in the sampling distribution of the correlation.  The standard example is that a single outlier in a large dataset may completely change the sample correlation.

Comment: @whuber You're right as usual. But that's only a worry for someone fixated on inference. Correlations are already more indirect than is needed for most research purposes; if you'r worried about their significance or confidence intervals, the sample is not large enough or the relationship is not strong enough. Also, in practice, how often do you see correlations with marked skewness where there weren't other grounds for transformation?

Comment: @Nick The concern is not confined to inference.  It implies that *no* correlation coefficient is trustworthy until one has investigated whether, and to what extent, it might have been influenced by outlying values.

Comment: Naturally I worry about outliers, and I worry about skewness insofar as it may imply outliers. If the question is changed to how much to worry about outliers, my emphasis would be different.